# iOS app rejected with: 2. 1 Performance: App Completeness and 5. 1.1 Legal: Privacy - Data Collection and Storage

Tags: ios, iphone

[image]My app was having Performance and App Completeness issue (for Guideline 2.1 - Information Needed) and I resolve that by providing demo account information.

And for other issue (i.e. Guideline 5.1.1 - Legal - Privacy - Data Collection and Storage
) in my app I am using mobile number to register for application.

So what should I do in response to Legal: Privacy - Data Collection and Storage issue?

Can anyone suggest second issue(5.1.1) is occurring because of first issue(2.1)?

Will apple developer through rejection because of second issue(5.1.1)

I have uploaded many apps on app store, but this is the first time I am getting the issue with the registration process. I can't change app flow because this is a client requirement.

Comment: Not sure how to answer this

Comment: Now Please check again...I have made it more clear.

Comment: Apple's requirement is pretty clear; your app has functionality that is not related to the user account but that functionality is only available after providing personal details and registering an account. Now, you say that you can't change it because of your client's requirement, but your client may need to change their requirements if they want their app approved.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion...:-)

Answer (score 0):

Add keys in info.plist:

Add this key with proper string

“Privacy - Contacts Usage Description”

More details :
[key help](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html)

[String help](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW73)